# Is it necessary to convert an image from gallery to base64 before uploading to amazon s3 server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, base64

A requirement for my mobile application is that I need to allow a user to select a image from their camera roll, and upload it to a s3 server.

In react native, i send a http request to an endpoint I created, in which a file is uploaded to amazon s3.

When sending the http request, i require to set a parameter to a file (The one a user selects). Do i need to change that file into a base64 format, and then send the http request, or can i just send the file as it is without any modifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your file as is in S3 (binary).

Whether your choose to upload it as base64 or binary depends on your application requirements only. S3 will take both.

Comment: Oh thank you. By binary, do you mean when an image is selected, set that file directly as a parameter without converting it into binary or something?

Comment: Yes, raw image, without conversion.

Comment: Oh thank you, so s3 can take non converted, raw files right?

Comment: Oh thank you man. I know this isn't related to this topic, however it is worth asking. When sending message using sockets, the data(a string) does it need to be encoded and decoded in UTF-8? If so why is this?

Comment: Please post another question for this, with more context.